# Fail to install homebrew on mac High Sierra: operation timed out

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew

I failed to install homebrew on mac. I tried a couple of things other people suggested for similar situations but still failed.

The terminal reads out:

```
> bogon:~ apple$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
> ==> This script will install: 
> /usr/local/bin/brew 
> /usr/local/share/doc/homebrew 
> /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
> /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
> /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew 
> /usr/local/Homebrew
> 
> Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
> ==> Downloading and installing Homebrew... 
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out 
> Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master --tags --force
```

Someone told me it has something to do with the git, and I tried the command "chown" , hoping to fix that but still failed (although I was not sure if I tried the right method).

Comment: This is a connection issue that has nothing to do with Homebrew. Are you behind a proxy? Can you open https://github.com/ in your browser?

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I am not sure whether I am behind a proxy. I can open GitHub though.

Comment: Might be networking issue or configure issue.