# Unable to install Homebrew

Tags: git, macos, terminal, proxy

I am trying to install Homebrew on my new Mac.

I have copied and tried to run the following line in my terminal:

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

But every time I do so, I get this message:

curl: (7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Operation timed out

I am in China, I use a VPN of course. My Mac is 10.15.4.

Comment: Great firewall of China?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49730532/fail-to-install-home-brew-on-mac-high-sierra

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the homebrew instructions.

If you have issues connecting to GitHub.com, you can use Git mirrors for Homebrew’s installation and brew update by setting HOMEBREW_BREW_GIT_REMOTE and/or HOMEBREW_CORE_GIT_REMOTE in your shell environment with this script:

```
export HOMEBREW_BREW_GIT_REMOTE="..."  # put your Git mirror of Homebrew/brew here
export HOMEBREW_CORE_GIT_REMOTE="..."  # put your Git mirror of Homebrew/homebrew-core here
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install
```

https://docs.brew.sh/Installation#git-remote-mirroring